# Take a high resolution (local) photo while streaming video via Android WebRTC?

Tags: android, android-camera, webrtc-android

I've created an Android WebRTC app and it is successfully streaming video from the device to other peers. However, I have a requirement to be able to simultaneously take a **high resolution** picture on the device and then save it locally.

I have tried to open my own camera session while WebRTC is running, but that causes WebRTC to shut down. I also tried various solutions that capture a frame from the local video stream, however the resolution is only as good as the stream itself (in my case, 640 x 480).

I have been able to create another camera and then turn off the RTC video, take the picture, and then re-enable RTC. However, the camera takes too long to both focus and establish the exposure.

I do have this working on iOS, but an Android solution is escaping me. Any help is appreciated!